# You are not authorized to perform this action in Yii

Tags: php, yii

When I open my site, it redirects to a blank page.

Any ideas?

live url:- http://hermosacreative.com/builder/index.php?r=site/login

```
CHttpException

You are not authorized to perform this action. (C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\auth\CAccessControlFilter.php:182)
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\auth\CAccessControlFilter.php(145): CAccessControlFilter->accessDenied(Object(CWebUser), 'You are not aut...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(38): CAccessControlFilter->preFilter(Object(CFilterChain))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\CController.php(1145): CFilter->filter(Object(CFilterChain))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\filters\CInlineFilter.php(58): CController->filterAccessControl(Object(CFilterChain))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(130): CInlineFilter->filter(Object(CFilterChain))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\CController.php(291): CFilterChain->run()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('error')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(368): CWebApplication->runController('site/error')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(351): CErrorHandler->renderError()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(218): CErrorHandler->renderException()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(131): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(CHttpException))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\hermosacreative.com\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(750): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#13 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(CHttpException))
#14 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of logic in your `SiteController#actionLogin` which requires the user to be logged in before it happens. All acts in the login action should be for a guest.

Remove any aspect of code which requires `Yii::app()->user->isGuest` to be `false`